# HTA Table Weirdness

Tags: vbscript, multiple-columns, hta

I dynamically create two columns in a table with column 1 having a bunch of buttons (to install apps on a remote PC) and column 2 being a multiple select box showing apps installed. I decided to add a span below the multiple select box showing the status of apps being installed or uninstalled via `UninstallStatusArea.InnerText` and weirdly the buttons in column 1 move down a line feed when `UninstallStatusArea.InnerText` contains characters, and then they move back up to their original location when `UninstallStatusArea.InnerText = ""`.

Why is that, or asked another way, how can I make the two columns completely independent of one another? It's actually not a huge deal, rather just an academic exercise that bothers the heck out of me.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Get System Information</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="Get System Information"
ID="GetPCInfo"
border="thin"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
SCROLL="NO"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
Public ApplicationList()

Sub Window_OnLoad
document.body.bgColor = "Silver"
document.body.style.fontFamily = "Calibri"
document.body.style.fontSize = "12 pt"
document.body.style.color = "black"

window.offscreenBuffering = True 'helps window refresh sometimes
window.resizeTo 1100,720 'width,height
window.moveTo (screen.width - document.body.clientwidth)/2, (screen.availheight - document.body.clientheight)/2

Tab1.InnerText = "Applications"

strComputer = "."

Panel1.InnerHTML = "<hr color=""black""><TABLE align=""center"" border=""0"" cellspacing=""1"" width=""80%"">" &_
    "<TR id=""Applications""><TD align=""left"">" &_
    "<button name=""InstallFF"" id=""InstallFF"" Title=""Clicking on this button will install FireFox."" value=""Install FF"" style=""background-color:orange; color:black; border: 1pt ridge black"">Install FireFox</button>" &_
    "<BR><BR><button name=""InstallChrome"" id=""InstallChrome"" Title=""Clicking on this button will install Chrome."" value=""Install Chrome"" style=""background-color:orange; color:black; border: 1pt ridge black"">Install Chrome</button>" &_
    "<BR><BR><BR><BR><button name=""UninstallApps"" id=""UninstallApps"" Title=""Clicking on this button will uninstall applications."" value=""Uninstall Apps""" &_
    " style=""background-color:red; color:black; border: 1pt ridge black"" onclick=""OnClickUninstallApps"">Uninstall Applications  </button><BR><span id = ""DataArea_Applications""></span>" &_
    "<input id=""DontPromptBox"" type=""checkbox"">Don't prompt, just do it!</TD>" &_
    "<TD align=""left"">" &_
    "<div style=""overflow:auto; width:550x;"">" &_
    "<select multiple size=""25"" name=""applistbox""></select></div><span id=""UninstallStatusArea"" font style=color:red;font-weight=bold;></span></TD></TR></Table>"

    UninstallStatusArea.InnerText = ""
    DontPromptBox.checked = True 

    Call Get_Applications(strComputer)
End Sub

'===================================
'==  SUB GET APPLICATION LIST  =====
'===================================
Sub Get_Applications(strComputerName)
Dim UnInstallList(), InstallDateList(), InstallRegList()
Dim strTemp, strTemp2, strTemp3, strValue1, strValue2, strValue3, strValue4, temp, temp2, temp3, temp4
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
strEntry1 = "DisplayName"
strEntry2 = "DisplayVersion"
strEntry3 = "UninstallString"
strEntry4 = "InstallDate"

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputerName & "/root/default:StdRegProv")
objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey, arrSubkeys

i = 0
For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys
    strTemp = "" : strTemp2 = "" : strTemp3 = ""
    strValue1 = "" : strValue2 = "" : strValue3 = "" : strValue4 = ""
    intRet1 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry1, strValue1)
    If intRet1 <> 0 Then objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry1, strValue1
    If strValue1 <> "" Then strTemp = strValue1
    objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry2, strValue2
    If strValue2 <> "" Then strTemp = strTemp & " Version: " & strValue2
    objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry3, strValue3
    If strValue3 <> "" Then strTemp2 = strValue3
    objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry4, strValue4
    If strValue4 <> "" Then strTemp3 = strValue4
    ReDim Preserve ApplicationList(i)
    ReDim Preserve UnInstallList(i)
    ReDim Preserve InstallDateList(i)
    ReDim Preserve InstallRegList(i)
    If Len(strTemp) > 8 Then
        If Len(strTemp2) > 8 Then
            ApplicationList(i) = strTemp
            UnInstallList(i) = strTemp2
            InstallDateList(i) = strTemp3
            InstallRegList(i) = strKey & strSubkey
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End if
Next

'now look at x64 keys
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputerName & "\root\cimv2")
Set colOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * From Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objItem In colOS
    strArch = objItem.OSArchitecture
Next
If InStr(strArch,"64") Then
    strKey = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
    objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey, arrSubkeys
    For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys
        strTemp = ""
        strTemp2 = ""
        strTemp3 = ""
        strValue1 = ""
        strValue2 = ""
        strValue3 = ""
        strValue4 = ""
        intRet1 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry1, strValue1)
        If intRet1 <> 0 Then objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry1, strValue1
        If strValue1 <> "" Then strTemp = strValue1
        objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry2, strValue2
        If strValue2 <> "" Then strTemp = strTemp & " Version: " & strValue2
        objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry3, strValue3
        If strValue3 <> "" Then strTemp2 = strValue3
        objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, strEntry4, strValue4
        If strValue3 <> "" Then strTemp3 = strValue4
        ReDim Preserve ApplicationList(i)
        ReDim Preserve UnInstallList(i)
        ReDim Preserve InstallDateList(i)
        ReDim Preserve InstallRegList(i)
        If Len(strTemp) > 8 Then
            If Len(strTemp2) > 8 Then
                ApplicationList(i) = strTemp
                UnInstallList(i) = strTemp2
                InstallDateList(i) = strTemp3
                InstallRegList(i) = strKey & strSubkey
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End if
    Next
End If

'alphabatize the array for easier readability
For a = UBound(ApplicationList) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For j = 0 to a
        If LCase(ApplicationList(j)) > LCase(ApplicationList(j+1)) then
            temp = ApplicationList(j+1)
            temp2 = UnInstallList(j+1)
            temp3 = InstallDateList(j+1)
            temp4 = InstallRegList(j+1)
            ApplicationList(j+1) = ApplicationList(j)
            UnInstallList(j+1) = UnInstallList(j)
            InstallDateList(j+1) = InstallDateList(j)
            InstallRegList(j+1) = InstallRegList(j)
            ApplicationList(j) = temp
            UnInstallList(j) = temp2
            InstallDateList(j) = temp3
            InstallRegList(j) = temp4
        End If
    Next
Next

'create the listbox from the array
For j = 0 To UBound(ApplicationList)
    Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
    objOption.Text = ApplicationList(j)
    If Len(InstallDateList(j)) > 0 then objOption.Text = objOption.Text & ", Install Date: " & InstallDateList(j)
    objOption.Value = UnInstallList(j)
    objOption.title = "Uninstall details found in Registry key:" & vbCrLf & InstallRegList(j)
    objOption.style.backgroundcolor = "#D4E5B3"
    applistbox.Add(objOption)
Next
End Sub

'==================================
'==  SUB UNINSTALL APPLICATIONS  ==
'==================================
Sub OnClickUninstallApps()
Dim i, j, iFind, UninstallString, UninstallRegString, strTemp23, strResults, iSelect, strComputerName
Dim objShell : set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strComputerName = "."
ShowCommand = 0
PSExec = "c:\pstools\psexec.exe -s -h \\"
strResults = ""
iSelect = 0

For i = 0 To applistbox.length - 1
    If applistbox(i).selected Then
        iSelect = 1
        UninstallStatusArea.InnerText = "Currently uninstalling " & applistbox(i).Text
        Call SleepWait(2) 'rather than uninstall, display the text for troubleshooting purposes
        UninstallStatusArea.InnerText = " "
        SleepWait(1)
        strResults = strResults & applistbox(i).Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 
    End If
Next
If iSelect = 1 Then
    Call ClearAppListbox()
    Call Get_Applications(strComputerName)
    set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Popup strResults,0,strComputerName & " - Uninstall Results"
Else
    MsgBox "No applications selected to uninstall.",vbOKOnly,"I did nothing"
End If
End Sub

'===============================
'==  SUB CLEAR APP LISTBOX  ====
'===============================
Sub ClearAppListbox()
For Each objOption in applistbox.Options
    objOption.RemoveNode
Next 
End Sub

'========================================
'= SleepWait - Momentary pause ==========
'========================================
Sub SleepWait(timeinseconds) 'Allows application to wait, if needed.
If timeinseconds = 0 Then timeinseconds = 0.2
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  .run "timeout " & timeinseconds, 0, True
End With
End Sub

</script>

<!--
===================================
== JAVASCRIPT =====================
===================================
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var panels = new Array("","panel1","panel2");
function panel(tab) {
for (i=1; i<panels.length; i++) {
    if (i == tab) {
        document.getElementById("tab"+i).className = "tabs tabs1";
        document.getElementById("panel"+i).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("tab"+i).className = "tabs tabs0";
        document.getElementById("panel"+i).style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body,td,th { font-family:Calibri }
.head { font-size:110%; font-weight:bold }
.panel {
background-color: skyblue;
border: solid 1px black;
height: 480px;
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
z-index: 0;
}
.tabs {
border-collapse: collapse;
color: black;
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 9pt;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 4px;
padding: 2px 4px 0px 4px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 1;
}
.tabs0 {
background-color: wheat;
border: solid 1px black;
}
.tabs1 {
background-color: skyblue;
border-color: black black silver black;
border-style: solid solid solid solid;
border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
hr {
border: 1;
width: 99%;
background-color: #0000FF;
height: 3px;
}

button {
color: white;
background-color: #4F7BA6;
border: 1px solid darkblue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1000">
<tr valign="top">
<td colspan="2">
&nbsp; <span class="tabs tabs1" id="tab1" onclick="panel(1)">Tab1</span>
&nbsp; <span class="tabs tabs0" id="tab2" onclick="panel(2)">Tab2</span>
<div class="panel" id="panel1" style="display:block">
</div>
<div class="panel" id="panel2" style="display:none">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot if the offending HTA]

To see what is happening, highlight a few apps and click on the red button (it actually does nothing now but bounce things up & down).

Comment: We are unable to reproduce your problem from the code snippet you posted. Please change that snippet to a [mcve]. You may also want to move towards formatting your HTML with CSS.

Comment: Edited to be minimal, complete and verified it reproduces my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Voting to reopen. The code may not be *strictly* minimal, but it does contain what's needed to reproduce and analyze the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a nested table into your panel, with a 2-column layout like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| +-------------------+ +----------------------------------+ |
| |                   | | +------------------------------+ | |
| |                   | | | Listbox                      | | |
| |                   | | |                              | | |
| |      Buttons      | | |                              | | |
| |                   | | |                              | | |
| |                   | | |                              | | |
| |                   | | +------------------------------+ | |
| |                   | | =============[span]============= | |
| +-------------------+ +----------------------------------+ |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The left cell contains your buttons, the right cell your listbox. Below the listbox you put an empty `<span>` (with the ID `UninstallStatusArea`). Whenever you put text into that `<span>` element it changes the height of the right cell and thus of the entire row, including the left cell. Changing the height of that cell is what moves the buttons, because they're vertically centered, so they'll shift whenever the cell's vertical size changes.

There are several ways how you could deal with this issue, for instance:

- Change the vertical alignment of the cells to `top` so they stick to the top rather than "float" in the middle:

  ```html
  <style type="text/css">
  body,td,th { font-family:Calibri; }
  td { vertical-align: top; }
  ...
  ```
- Set a height for the `<span>` element:

  ```html
  <span id="UninstallStatusArea" style="color:red;...;height:40px;">
  ```
- Move the span to a second table row:

  ```html
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><span id="UninstallStatusArea" ...></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```
- Remove the table(s) and switch to a completely `<div>` and CSS based layout.

Comment: Danke schoen! Do you have a favorite site(s) off the top of your head that you'd recommend for learning how to use CSS effectively and correctly? Scripting I can do, CSS and HTML I'm not so experienced with.

Comment: Does Google count? ;þ If you speak German, I found [SelfHTML](https://de.selfhtml.org/) pretty helpful when I started learning HTML and CSS. The site has undergone major changes over the past years, though, so I can't say if it's still as good as it was.